# Python not replacing special character: Â­

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with Excel, via pandas/csv. There's a cell value, RCReg2Â-, that refuses to sanitize to RCReg2.

Here's the relevant part of the dictionary (replacements_map) found in `old_new_46.py`:

`replacements_map = {"RCReg2\u00c2\u00ad-": "RCReg2"}`

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet
import csv 
from csv import writer
import sys
# a python file that contains a dictionary of old values and replacement ones
from old_new_46 import replacements_map

def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as write_obj:
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

def get_file_encoding(file):
    rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
    return encoding

# data = input('Please enter filename: ')
# data += ('.csv')
data = 'anquar_FULL46.csv'

# my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
# print(my_encoding)
my_encoding = "utf-8"
df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding=my_encoding, header=None, low_memory=False)

csv_rows = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

for row in csv_rows:
    for item in row:
        str(item).strip()

sanitized_rows = []
#encode each dictionary key, value as a unicode string
#replacements_map = {str(k).encode("utf-8"): str(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in replacements_map.items()}

for row in csv_rows:
    sanitized_rows.append(
        [(replacements_map[item] if (item in replacements_map) else item)
         for item
         in row]
    )

file = "sanitized_" + data

for row in sanitized_rows:
    append_list_as_row(file, row)
```

This works like a charm other than the RCReg2Â­ part. The df is already being read in unicode, so I don't see how it's not recognizing the unicode RCReg2\u00c2\u00ad-.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you sure there is a soft hyphen (`\u00ad`) in `RCReg2Â-` between `Â` and `-`?

Comment: Neighter do these work:
"RCReg2\u00c2\u00ad": "RCReg2",
 "RCReg2\u00c2-": "RCReg2"
```